# Enable AspectJ on Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: weblogic, aspectj

I would like to implement AspectJ into Weblogic ear module to change the behaviour during development phase. This is my set up:

- 1 `sample.ear` file with class Sample.java need to change behaviour:

  ```
  public class Sample {
      public String getName() {
          return "Sample Name";
      }
  }
  ```

and have 1 servlet class to call this class at init method

- 1 `sampleAspect.jar` file with aop.xml embedded inside the META-INF

  ```
  public aspect SampleAspect {
      pointcut getName() : call(* *.Sample.getName(..));
      String around() : getName() {
          return "Sample Name Aspect";
      }
  }
  ```

In Weblogic setup, I set the aspectjrt.jar and sampleAspect.jar to the classpath as
`classpath=C:\aspectj\lib\aspectjrt.jar;C:\library\sampleAspect.jar;%CLASSPATH%`

also put the `-javaagent:C:\aspectj\aspectjwearver.jar` into the java argument

Deploy the sample.ear as a module of Weblogic

When start up Weblogic server, I saw this log in the server log of server

```
[EventInfoClassLoader@302eb2b4] info register aspect SampleAspect
```

But I check the servlet, it return "Sample Name", not the one in the aspect.

What did I do wrong?

> Updated:

I changed to `execution(* *.Sample.getName(..))` as suggested by Amir, but still the same problem.

This is the information of aop.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN"
"http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose" />
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.mycode.aspect.SampleAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your didn't provide the servlet code. So I'm guessing the aspect is meant to intercept when the "getName" is actually being executed. If so, use "execution" instead of "call".

Comment: Thanks for your sharing @Amir, I changed to `execution` as your suggest, but still not working at all.